# Cubic root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Is there anyway to solve this without substituting with the values?
Prove that: $$\frac{1+10w^2}{1-2w} + \frac{2+17w}{2+3w} = 6$$. (Where $w$ & $w^2$ are the cubic roots of unity)

Comment: Do you mean $w$ & $w^2$ or $w$ and $w_2$?

Comment: By "solve" you mean to show the left hand side actually does equal six?

Comment: **Hint**: What happens if you multiply both sides by $(1-2w)(2+3w)$? Also, recall that $w^2=-w-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'trick' method: consider

$$6-\dfrac{2+17\omega}{2+3\omega} = \dfrac{12 + 18\omega-2-17\omega}{2+3\omega}=\dfrac{10+w}{2+3\omega}$$

Now if we multiply through by $\dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega^2}\dots$

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$1+w+w^2 = 0$, as $$w(1+w+w^2) = w+w^2+w^3 = 1+w+w^2$$
 and $w \ne 1$. Now we have
$$ (1-2w)(2+3w) = 2 - w - 6w^2 = 2 - w - 6(-1-w) = 8+5w $$
and 
\begin{align*}
  (1+10w^2)(2+3w) + (1-2w)(2+17w) &= 2+ 3w+20w^2 + 30 + 2 +13 w - 34w^2\\
        &= 34 + 16w - 14w^2\\
        &= 34 + 16w + 14 + 14w\\
        &= 48 + 30w
\end{align*} 
And therefore
$$
  \frac{1+ 10w^2}{1-2w} + \frac{2+17w}{2+3w} = \frac{48+30w}{8+5w} = 6.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $w^2=-w-1$ gives you
$$\begin{align}\frac{1+10w^2}{1-2w}+\frac{2+17w}{2+3w}&=\frac{(1+10(-w-1))(2+3w)+(2+17w)(1-2w)}{(1-2w)(2+3w)}\\&=\frac{-64w^2-34w-16}{2-w-6w^2}\\&=\frac{-64(-w-1)-34w-16}{2-w-6(-w-1)}\\&=\frac{6(5w+8)}{5w+8}\\&=6\end{align}$$